# syntax error near unexpected token `check_call' . Syntax error in terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm trying to enter this command in Mac terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from subprocess import check_call
from os.path import basename, dirname, splitext, join
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

app = argv[-1]
ldid_path = join(dirname(__file__), 'ldid')
obj_path = join(app, splitext(basename(app))[0])

if '-gta' not in argv:
    check_call([ldid_path, '-S', obj_path])
else:
    with NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', 0) as f:
        f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
        """)
        f.flush()
        check_call([ldid_path, '-S' + f.name, obj_path])
```

But I got a error:

```
iMac-Oleg:ldid olegmelnik$ f.flush()
```

> check_call([ldid_path, '-S' + f.name, obj_path])
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `check_call'

How to fix this? Thanks so much...

Comment: That isn't "a command". That is a python script. You cannot type it out line-by-line at your terminal prompt.

Comment: But then you would be seeing errors that `from` is an invalid command way earlier in the file.

Comment: @EtanReisner what I need to do?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I'm surprised at that myself though I mostly figured they were just ignored earlier.

Comment: @olezko46 Put that code into a file `something.py` and then run that file through python: `python something.py`. Obviously you can use whatever name you want for the file.

Comment: We don't understand what you are doing. You need to update your question and explain how exactly you are trying to use this code.

Comment: @EtanReisner Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/olegmelnik/Desktop/ldid3.py", line 13, in <module>
    check_call([ldid_path, '-S', obj_path])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/olegmelnik/Desktop/ldid', '-S', '/Users/olegmelnik/Desktop/ldid3.py/ldid3']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: @olezko46 That error says that the call to `ldid` failed. Do you have an `ldid` script/binary at that location? The script expects it to be in the same directory as `ldid3.py`.

Comment: @EtanReisner http://youtu.be/tMneN1P2T1w Look at this video.

Comment: The error message is altogether different from what's in your question.  Update your question with correct diagnostics.

Comment: Posting a video is a huge waste of both your time and ours.

Comment: Agreeing with everything triplee just said (and adding that video was much too long for its purpose) the issue you have there is that python's `os.path.dirname` is stupid and doesn't return '.' for paths with no directory separator. Run `python ./ldid3.py` and it should work better (assuming that `ldid` binary works correctly).

Comment: @EtanReisner 
iMac-Oleg:ldid olegmelnik$ python ./ldid3.py
minimal/mapping.h(54): _assert(false); errno=20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ldid3.py", line 13, in <module>
    check_call([ldid_path, '-S', obj_path])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./ldid', '-S', './ldid3.py/ldid3']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: That looks approximately correct. It just means `ldid` is returning an error. Now you get to figure out why. Try running it by hand and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/olegmelnik/Desktop/ldid', '-S', '/Users/olegmelnik/Desktop/ldid3.py/ldid3']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is what `check_call` does.  If you don't want that, don't use `check_call`.  See the [`subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more information.